# Select2 - Tell if user entered in new search choice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, jquery-select2

Right my select2 options look like this:

```
$scope.select2Options = {
    ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/api/locations/',
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                search: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data) {
            var locations = data.locations.map(formatLocations);
            return { results: locations }; 
        }
    },
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function () {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id: term,
                text: term
            };
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, I am using the angular-ui-select2 directive, but my options would be the same if I were using the plain jquery select2.

The code works fine for allowing users to add search terms, but I am wondering if there is a good way to tell when a user has entered in a new search choice.

Right now I can only think of:

1) wait for the user to blur out of the input 
2) Fire an ajax call to my server to see if it contains the input's current value

Downside is that I always do 2), even if the user is selecting an existing choice.

I am hoping there is some sort of event like 'onNewSearchChoice' I could listen to.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you look at the `select2-selecting` option? I'm not sure if that's what you need but that's the closest thing I saw in the docs.

Comment: Also, you could use a shared variable in the `query` callback and `createSearchChoice` callback to keep track of when it's a new choice, e.g.: http://pastebin.com/p63ZJcmR

Comment: 'select2-selecting' is exactly what I am looking for!  I can't believed I missed it.  Add your comment as an answer and I'll select it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select2-selecting` event, documented here:
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation

Also, you could use a shared variable in the query callback and createSearchChoice callback to keep track of when it's a new choice, e.g.:

```
var newTerm = false;

$scope.select2Options = {
    query: function(query) {
        newTerm = false;
        ...
    },

    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        term = $.trim(term);
        if (term) newTerm = term;
        ...
    }
};
```